# Pass the values into ng blur function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I trying to pass id to search function as a parameter,when user select one name

```
<input type="text" ng-model="RegionName" placeholder="Region" ng-blur="search(item.id)" uib-typeahead="item as item.name for item in items | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:10" class="form-control" >
```

My JSON data:

```
json : {"id":"000","name":"value1"},{"id":"001","name":"value2"}
```

Angularjs Code:

```
 $scope.search = function (code) {
            alert(code);
  }
```

I am getting Code is undefined.

Where is my mistake.Please give your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `ng-blur="search(item.id)` to `ng-blur="search(RegionName.id)` and it will work., because you bind data to another property `RegionName`.

Also I see that `ng-blur` has issue with typeahead, so I suggest to use use `ng-change`.

See this working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9aIiGQXHyQ5ZHhYHRNT5?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks sir @anoop

Comment: glad to help you :)